# APACHE SOLR version 7.4 integrating with django haystack

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I m trying to integrate Apache Solr into my Django application to add some search functionality. I have generated the `schema.xml` file and rebuilt the index. When I try to search for a term in my application, I'm getting the following error:

```
 app_label, model_name = raw_result[DJANGO_CT].split(".")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I am using Apache Solr version 7.4 on Windows.